# tex4ht: include *.pdf image - need condition in configuration file

Tags: graphics, pdf, conditionals, tex4ht

I use `tex4ht` to compile my document.

In case if user includes `.pdf` image, I handle this situation in the following way (`.cfg` file):

```
\Configure{graphics*} 
{pdf}  
{\Link[\csname Gin@base\endcsname .pdf]{}{}% link the pdf figure 
\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname" align=center border=0}%  Show the png
\EndLink  
}
```

I want to realize the following idea:

If `imagename.png` doesn't exist, then paste `default.png` (the same in all cases) image, otherwise reflect `imagename.png`.

Could someone help me to write such condition in configuration file, if it is possible.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, you don't want to convert your pdf images to png?

Comment: There are a lot of documents which where created previously and *.png file is absent. And I want in such case reflect informative image instead of "PIC" word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use small [Javascript trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222073/2467963):

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{graphics*} 
{pdf}  
{\Link[\csname Gin@base\endcsname .pdf]{}{}% link the pdf figure 
\Picture[pict]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname .png width="\expandafter\the\csname Gin@req@width\endcsname" align=center border=0 onerror="this.src='missing.png'"}%  Show the png
\EndLink  
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

the important part is `onerror="this.src='missing.png'"`.

Some sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=180pt]{hello.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=180pt]{world.pdf}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]